# How can you send an object using jQuery's .data() method?

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure this is possible, but...

Let's say I have the following object:

```
var myData = { 1 : 1. 2 : 2 }
```

How can I attach the object to the following url, using jQuery's .data method.

```
$('.link').html('<a href="#" data-test="' + myData + '">test</a>');
```

If I bind a click function to the following url, I should be able to retrive **myData**

```
$('.link a').on('click', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).data('test');
})
```

But it's not working... i get a string value called: ["object Object"]

**So i am thinking, I need to prepare the -myData- object before I send it using jQuery's .data method.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a data object, don't set it as an attribute, use the .data() setter to set the value of `test`

```
$('<a href="#">test</a>').appendTo($('.link').empty()).data('test', myData);
```

then

```
$('.link a').on('click', function(e) {
    var myData = $(this).data('test');
})
```

Comment: Ty for helping... I will try it, but can you explain what is the difference between how I tried to do it initially?

Comment: @webmasters `myData` is an object when you convert it to a string it becomes `[object Object]` otherwise you need to use a function like [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert the data object to proper string format.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myData = { '1' : 1, '2' : 2 };
var $anchor = $('<a />', {href:'#', text : 'test'}).data('test', myData);

$('.link').empty().append($anchor);


$('.link a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log($(this).data('test'));
});
```